# Avoiding toBlocking in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

I found below code(modified for brevity), which is buggy, and has flaws as far as I can tell.

1. Its using toBlocking() which is not recommended in general, and has been used within reactive context
2. It returns single(); so as soon as it gets the single item from the stream, it terminates it, ignoring the rest of the items which is not desirable.

While I believe I can solve the issue, by removing `single` to `last`? Can someone explain, how can I get about removing the use of `toBlocking()` here?

```
observableList.map(incentiveDetailsList -> {
        List<SomeObject> list = mapThisList(incentiveDetailsList);
        return Observable.just(list)
                    .flatMap(Observable::from)
                    .flatMap(item -> {
                        Request request = createRequest(item);
                        String accountNumber = item.getAccountNumber();
                        return serviceThatReturnsObservable.load(request)
                                .doOnError(onError -> {
                                    Observable.error(new Exception("some context"));
                                })
                                .map(response -> {
                                    handleError(response);
                                    return responseMap.put(accountNumber, buildResponse(response.getResponse()));
                                });
                    })
                    .map(resp -> mapResponse(store, incentiveDetailsList, responseMap))
                    .toBlocking()
                    .single();
})
```

Comment: Whenever you feel to use map + toBlocking, you need `flatMap`. Also `just+flatMap(from)` you can replace with `from`.

Comment: thanks, I believe I was on right track, but my issue is when I replace `map + toBlocking` with `.flatMap(resp-> {return resp});` I'm getting compilation error. Somewhere I'm making a naive mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace map + toBlocking with `flatMap` (or `concatMap`):

```
 observableList.flatMap(incentiveDetailsList -> {
    List<SomeObject> list = mapThisList(incentiveDetailsList);
    return Observable.from(list)
           .flatMap(item -> {
               Request request = createRequest(item);
               String accountNumber = item.getAccountNumber();
               return serviceThatReturnsObservable.load(request)
                   /* this has no effect:
                            .doOnError(onError -> {
                                Observable.error(new Exception("some context"));
                            })
                    */
                    .map(response -> {
                         handleError(response);
                         return responseMap.put(accountNumber, 
                            buildResponse(response.getResponse()));
                    });
            })
            .map(resp -> mapResponse(store, incentiveDetailsList, responseMap));
})
```

Comment: Can you explain `this has no effect:`?

Comment: That code doesn't handle any errors, plus it creates an Observable and throws it away immediately.